# When obtaining data from api get in some instances NULL

Tags: php, api, cryptocurrency

I have a problem getting data via api. When the crypto == "BTC" or "LTC", and everything works as it should, but in other cases the balance = NULL, you do not know what it could be? Here's code:

```
if ($krypto == "BTC") {
    $json = file_get_contents('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/addrs/1BSJxTKxu2RZfHCtEFpXShypn73Xmpry6N/balance');
}
elseif ($krypto == "LTC") {
    $json = file_get_contents('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/ltc/main/addrs/LgzoEpUijQ39bWuY8XXQ2NUqrerebdE3w9/balance');
}
elseif ($krypto == "ETH") {
    $json = file_get_contents('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/addrs/0x7d8b9d28d373394fb23242eb838345f69c2ec25d/balance');
}
elseif ($krypto == "DASH") {
    $json = file_get_contents('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/dash/main/addrs/XfUYFuyaca53cZHvJ9q679RqEo58wNRthp/balance');
}
elseif ($krypto == "DOGE") {
    $json = file_get_contents('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/doge/main/addrs/DCrzwReRzPuaipX1ziQoTiLqotLD3sKMUz/balance');
}

$obj = json_decode($json);
$balance = $obj->balance / 100000000;
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as your question yesterdaay: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65892740/server-error-in-obtaining-data-through-api

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: How often are you running it the script? They may have a rate limiter.

Comment: Yes, but it was locked, but I didn't get an answer. I looked at the server error log and it does not report any error. Error 500 was caused by a piece of code other than this, so I'm querying again

Comment: I run btc to much more and it works, but other cryptocurreny not, it's weird

Comment: The site may be blocking you for some reason. The code is fine.

Comment: Dump the output of the `file_get_contents()` before you `json_decode()` it. It may not contain what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but first I have to run the code xD

Comment: @AlexHowansky
So what should the code look like?

Comment: Just `var_dump($json)` to see if it actually contains the JSON you're expecting.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I tried it and it works normally